# Getting cors error while uploading file on mapbox s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, mapbox, mapbox-gl, geotiff, tilesets

We are trying to upload geotiff file to mapbox studio via it's uploads api.

I have image URL which is stored in firestore
We want to upload that file to mapbox and get the tile set but at putObject it's giving cors error.

Which can be used to show it on map

References :
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/blob/main/docs/services.md#createupload

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/uploads/

`

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const getCredentials = () => {

return uploadsClient

```
.createUploadCredentials()

.send()

.then(response => response.body);
```

}

const putFileOnS3 = (credentials) => {

const s3 = new AWS.S3({

```
accessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,

secretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,

sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken,

region: 'us-east-1'
```

});

return s3.putObject({

```
Bucket: credentials.bucket,

Key: credentials.key,

Body: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.mbtiles')
```

}).promise();

};

getCredentials().then(putFileOnS3);`

This is giving cors error. Can I edit mapbox s3 bucket permission or is there any other way to upload file via API, that I can get mapbox tileSet?